# Why is the (virtual) destructor of the derived class not called when deleting an array through a pointer to the base class?

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, polymorphism, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have an `Animal` class with a virtual destructor, and a derived class `Cat`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Animal
{
    Animal() { std::cout << "Animal constructor" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~Animal() { std::cout << "Animal destructor" << std::endl; }
};

struct Cat : public Animal
{
    Cat() { std::cout << "Cat constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~Cat() override { std::cout << "Cat destructor" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    const Animal *j = new Cat[1];
    delete[] j;
}
```

This gives the output:

> Animal constructor  
> Cat constructor  
> Animal destructor

I don't understand why is the `Cat`'s destructor not called, when my base class destructor is virtual?

Comment: cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/asahqsvxM. What compiler are you using?

Comment: which standard version are you using? Please only tag that and remove the other

Comment: Totally OT, but if a function doesn't have any arguments then you don't need to write anything. Instead of e.g. `Cat(void)` only `Cat()` will work.

Comment: Also OT, but the member should not be a raw pointer, and when it is you need to consider the rule of 3 / 5.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number clang 14.0.3 on macOS reproduces OP's output for me.

Comment: @Botje I can only reproduce the output with gcc when `Animal::~Animal` is **not** virtual (https://godbolt.org/z/eKndcKGbM)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I changed your first compiler explorer link to x86-64 clang 16.0.0 and got OP's output.

Comment: silly bugs require silly thinking; maybe a `#define virtual` somewhere? Check with `#ifdef virtual \n #error "virtual is defined" \n #endif`

Comment: Minimal repro:
https://godbolt.org/z/EaaYnKPMP
Note the const isn't needed, but array new/delete is.

Comment: @Raf no silly thinking required. We already found out that nothing but posted code is needed to reproduce the output with clang https://godbolt.org/z/aKxMnozbW. Only OP needs to clarify what they are using

Comment: (I've answered this, but interesting to note that GCC gets just as confused later if you change the number of cats allocated to _2_)

Comment: You almost never want an array of polymorphic types. You want an array of (smart) *pointers* to such types instead.

Comment: Just to follow up on the `Cat(void)` vs. `Cat()` thing—in C, you should use the former (the `void` distinguishes between unspecified and empty arity), but in C++ it's an oxymoron (this cruft has been sensibly removed) and you should use the latter. Highly recommended reading: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/287002

Comment: Since Cat and Animal are not the same size, you are going to have an issue if you try to index more than one Cat in the Animal array. This is also probably related to why some compilers are not immediately getting confused on this specific example.

Comment: Deleting through the converted pointer is UB, as one (correct) answer says. There is no guarantee in general that the converted pointer points to the beginning of the array. (in case of multiple base classes, for one) Storing the result of `new[]` in a variable declared with `const auto` should keep the **type** and **value** of `j` appropriate for use with `delete[]`, and the code would work as expected. It's (almost) no use trying to find a sensible reason for a specific behaviour in presence of UB. It resorts to compiler psychology, not logic.

Answer (score 42):

Note that whilst a `Cat` is an `Animal`, an array of `Cat`s is *not* an array of `Animal`s. In other words, arrays are *invariant* in C++, not *covariant* like they are in some other languages.

So you are up-casting this array and this later confuses the compiler. You must do array `delete[]` in this case on the correct, original, type - `Cat*`.

Note that you would have similar issues for the same reason if you allocated an array of 2 or more `Cat`s, cast this to an `Animal*` and then tried to use the second or subsequent Animal.

Comment: Typo: down casting -> Upcasting (Downcasting would be Animal -> Cat)

Comment: `std::vector` to the rescue

Comment: Does a tool like CPPCheck see the issue?
Can someone point a precise wording, perhaps in cppreference, about why, while storing a derived * as base * is legal, the unexpected delete [] is called?

Comment: @Dharmesh946 I added such answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the terms *invariant* and *covariant*? I tried looking them up on a web search, but there was too much (off-diagonal) covariance with the math/data term.

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

Comment: This would become even clearer if you had a data member in `Animal` and added a second data member to `Cat`.  Since then `sizeof(Animal)!=sizeof(Cat)`, array indexing would be completely off.  An array of *smart pointers* to `Animal` would work as expected since the destructor would get called for each pointer, and pointers are genuinely polymorphic.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It's not even an array thing. In C++, a `Cat` is not an `Animal`, full stop. C++ simply does not fully implement (I want to say: "believe in") the OOP is-a relationship, not in the way e.g. Java does. We can use the is-a model to design/plan class hierarchies. But the correct mental model for actually writing C++ is that a `Cat` only *contains* a (special) `Animal` object, as a base-class subobject. `std::vector` doesn't help much: a `std::vector<Animal>` cannot hold `Cat`s.  Assigning a `std::vector<Cat>` to one makes a copy of only the `Animal` part of each `Cat`.

Comment: @HTNW what you say all makes sense, but frankly, has nothing to do with my confusion. A `std::vector<Animal*>` would be fine with a cat. Its obvious that a `std::vector<Animal>` is not a vector of pointers to `Animal`, but as soons as c-arrays are involved I get confused

Answer (score 10):

It's Undefined Behaviour in my understanding because of (in 7.6.2.9 Delete,p2, Emphasis mine):

> In a **single-object delete expression**, the value of the operand of
> delete may be a null pointer value, a pointer value that resulted from
> a previous **non-array new-expression, or a pointer to a base class
> subobject of an object created by such a new-expression**. If not, the
> behavior is undefined. In an **array delete expression**, the value of
> the operand of delete **may be a null pointer value** **or a pointer
> value that resulted from a previous array new-expression**...

Which basically means that for `delete[]` the type must be the exact one from `new[]` (no base class sub-objects allowed like `delete`).

So for the reason that is like this - in my opinion this time is obvious - the implementation needs to know how much is the full object size so it can iterate to the next array element.

*I wrote counter arguments for why this could be different - but after some thought (and reading the comments) - I realised that such a solution is solving X-Y problem.*

Comment: This encourages dangerous behaviour though. If you allow this then you are basically saying `Animal* a = new Cat[2]; delete[] a;` is ok. This would implicitly imply that `a` is useful on its own when it very much is not. `a[1]` is undefined behaviour at this point as array index uses the type (`a[i]` is defined as `(a+i)`) which moves on `a` by `sizeof(Animal)` bytes and _not_ `sizeof(Cat)` bytes which it must do. So just avoiding this whole issue by not allowing `a` to be useful across the board is probably the right thing to do.

Comment: Re "the implementation needs to store the number of array elements anyway": The number of elements may be found dynamically by an end marker. The destructor iterates the array *anyway* if element destructors are called, so that's not a time loss. The allocated block will probably store a block size, but that may not be the minimum required for the array size (it could always be a power of 2, for example). If the element type does *not* have a destructor, then the end marker is irrelevant and no iteration at all will take place -- the block can be released right away wholesale.

Comment: In addition, the first assignment in `main` does not guarantee in general that the `Animal*`, pointing to the first element of the array as an `Animal` would have the same **value** as the pointer returned by `new Cat[]`, especially if `Animal` is not the first base class of `Cat` and EBO did not kick in on the previous ones. So yes, in general, deleting through the converted pointer ought to be UB. Using `const auto` instead should fix it :-P

Answer (score 9):

I answer to my own comment:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete (emphasis mine)

> **For the second (array) form**, expression must be a null pointer value
> or a pointer value previously obtained by an array form of
> new-expression whose allocation function was not a non-allocating form
> (i.e. overload (10)). **The pointed-to type of expression must be
> similar to the element type of the array object**. If expression is
> anything else, including if it's a pointer obtained by the non-array
> form of new-expression, the behavior is undefined.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing

> Informally, two types are similar if, ignoring top-level
> cv-qualification:
>
> - they are the same type; or
> - they are both pointers, and the pointed-to types are similar;or
> - they are both pointers to member of the same
>   class, and the types of the pointed-to members are similar; or
> - they are both arrays of the same size or both arrays of unknown bound, and
>   the array element types are similar. (until C++20)
> - they are both arrays of the same size or at least one of them is array of unknown
>   bound, and the array element types are similar.

So far as I understand, inheritance is not similarity...

Comment: Inheritance cannot be similarity indeed. Note that the array contains values, not references, and a `Cat` values is larger than an `Animal` value, so it won't fit there. That makes the cast from `Cat *` to `Animal *` invalid *when pointing to an array*, but since the type does not indicate it's pointing to an array and for single instance it is valid, the programmer has to mind this.

Comment: ah yes - note that if you allocate more than one cat then for example `j[1]` calculates a wrong address for the second cat, because it uses sizeof(Animal) instead of sizeof(Cat)

Comment: Where do they get the "similarity" idea from? The standard only seems to say "pointer value that resulted from a previous array new-expression". Perhaps there is a constraint or additional remark somewhere which is not cross-referenced from 7.6.2.9? By the way, I must assume that "value" in the standard means "typed value" (and not simply numerical value, or the OP's code would work). But the standard does not define its use of "value" afaics, which may be a defect.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica it came from http://wg21.link/cwg2474

Comment: @Cubbi Interesting, thanks. As an aside, the definition of "similar" is unintelligible to me. (I assume they mean roughly that cv-qualifications don't matter and that one can omit array bounds, but that's only a qualified guess. Examples would really help here.)

Answer (score 7):

My only criticism of the other answers is that they are too tame. Arrays work because the entries all have the same size, so the starting address of the entry with index 5 can be computed easily. Casting array of Derived to array of Base (which is what you are doing here) could have much worse consequences than you have shown. (If the array happens to have only one entry or Derived has no new data members you *might* be OK.) A[1].method() will probably do something strange because (Base*)(A)+1 is not even the starting address of any object. The method will read the wrong data, and the effect of any change will be highly unpredictable. Any call to a virtual function will use an entirely meaningless vtable pointer, so who knows what 'code' will be executed. Even if that call is not an immediate disaster, you might override a vtable pointer. Destruction of the array will almost certainly delete some meaningless 'pointers'.

Pointer to single object (allocated & deleted without '[]') is fine. You can cast to Base*, dynamic_cast back, and call virtual functions. That's why Ayxan Haqverdili's suggestion works. Array of X should never have anything except objects of run-time type X, and new[] (even new[1]) creates arrays.

Comment: "they are two tame": did you mean "too tame"?

Answer (score 3):

Others have explained the issue, but if you want an array of polymorphic objects, you want an array of pointers. Here's one way:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Animal>> animals;
animals.push_back(std::make_unique<Cat>());
animals.push_back(std::make_unique<Dog>());
animals.push_back(std::make_unique<Monkey>());
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cat's destructor is not called because the pointer **J** is declared as pointer to a constant Animal. When you delete an array of objects through a pointer to a base class with a virtual destructor the destructor of each derived class object is not called unless the pointer type is of derived class.

So for calling the Cat Destructor. modity the pointer type to

```
int main()
{
const Cat* j=new Cat[1];
delete[] j;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Make the Cat destructor also virtual and the code works as expected.

Comment: As the destructor of the base class (Animal) is declared virtual, the destructor of the subclass Cat will implicitly be virtual too, as virtual-ness is propagated.

Comment: Please read attentively all answers and comments, as the issue is tricky. You'll see that it may "work" but not on all compilers and not in all situations, and rightly so.